# how to translate the content of a button?

Tags: angular

I would like to translate a button in Angular.

The problem is that the translation isn't in my button but outside.

I have a second problem,

Here is an example:

[image]

I think that the problem is this here?

```
<input type="submit"
```

Here is the code

```
<p class="step3 help-3" style="top: 178px; position: relative; float: right;">
   <span class="inputButtons medium">
    <input type="submit" (click)="goToFase(2)" *ngIf="fase == 1" style="width: 200px;margin-top: 0px !important;">
        {{'1587' | t }}
   
   </span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write it like this

```html
<input type="submit" [value]=" {{'1587' | t }}">
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, how to handle the `[value]` ? I have to put  ->  `(click)="goToFase(2)" *ngIf="fase == 1" style="width: 200px;margin-top: 0px !important;"`> 
 inside ?

Comment: You could actually write it like this
```html
<button (click)="goToFase(2)" *ngIf="fase == 1" style="width: 200px;margin-top: 0px !important;">
  text
</button>
```

Comment: @ vue ang: Thank you  vue ang it's ok ^^